# How to group documents of a collection to a map with unique field values as key and count of documents as mapped value in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I need a mongodb query to get the list or map of values with unique value of the *field(f)* as the **key** in the collection and count of documents having the same value in the field(f) as the mapped **value**. How can I achieve this ?

Example:

```
Document1: {"id":"1","name":"n1","city":"c1"}
Document2: {"id":"2","name":"n2","city":"c2"}
Document3: {"id":"3","name":"n1","city":"c3"}
Document4: {"id":"4","name":"n1","city":"c5"}
Document5: {"id":"5","name":"n2","city":"c2"}
Document6: {"id":"6,""name":"n1","city":"c8"}
Document7: {"id":"7","name":"n3","city":"c9"}
Document8: {"id":"8","name":"n2","city":"c6"}
```

Query result should be something like this if group by field is "name":

```
{"n1":"4",
 "n2":"3",
 "n3":"1"}
```

It would be nice if the list is also sorted in the descending order.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting, using data points as field names (keys) is somewhat considered an anti-pattern and makes tooling difficult.  Nonetheless if you insist on having data points as field names you can use this complicated aggregation to perform the query output you desire...

**Aggregation**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: { _id: "$name", "count": { "$sum": 1} }
    },
    {
        $sort: { "count": -1 }
    },
    {
        $group: { _id: null, "values": { "$push": { "name": "$_id", "count": "$count" } } }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            _id: 0,
            results:
            {
                $arrayToObject:
                {
                    $map:
                    {
                        input: "$values",
                        as: "pair",
                        in: ["$$pair.name", "$$pair.count"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$results" }
    }
])
```

**Aggregation Explanation**

This is a 5 stage aggregation consisting of the following...

1. $group - get the count of the data as required by name.
2. $sort - sort the results with count descending.
3. $group - place results into an array for the next stage.
4. $project - use the $arrayToObject and $map to pivot the data such
   that a data point can be a field name.
5. $replaceRoot - make results the top level fields.

**Sample Results**

```
{ "n1" : 4, "n2" : 3, "n3" : 1 }
```

For whatever reason, you show desired results having count as a string, but my results show the count as an integer.  I assume that is not an issue, and may actually be preferred.

Comment: Thanks man. It helped. Yeah integers are fine too, I just needed the stats. I tried some aggregations but didn't work out. Thanks !!